# How can I programatically determine the maximum size in bytes of a character in a specific charset?

Tags: java, character-encoding

I am getting all supported charsets by using :

```
Object[] Charsets = Charset.availableCharsets().keySet().toArray();
```

I now need to iterate through each character that can be encoded in that charset. To do this I thought about using the maximum number of bytes for each encoding and going through `Byte.MIN_VALUE` to `Byte.MAX_VALUE` for each byte. That byte array I then pass it through the `String` constructor that accepts a `byte[]` array and a specific encoding.

However can't find any clues on how I can determine the maximum length in bytes of a character representation in a specific charset.

I tried using the space character (i.e. " ") to create a string in that encoding and using `.getBytes("<specific charset>").length`. However I believe this only works for fixed size charsets. There are charsets in which the encoding of a character can have a variable number of bytes.

This is not a commercial software so it does not need a pretty solution. I need to create a sort of visual map of each supported charset. Each character representation is written into an image. I am also not sure on how I should select a font that can properly display all characters of a charset.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
charset.newEncoder().maxBytesPerChar()
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Thank you very much. I'll accept the answer asap.