# How to determine the minimum number of bytes required by a character?

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, mbstring

Is there a way to determine for sure the minimum number of bytes required by a character in a specific encoding? Like one of the encodings supported by the mbstring extension. The value will be 1 for UTF-8, 2 for UTF-16, etc.

**I don't want to obtain the length of a particular string or char.**

I want to know the minimum char size supported by a given encoding, according to it's specification.

I currently use this code:

```
<?php

function flawed_detection($encoding)
{
    // I use 'a' in the hope that this char need the least number of bytes in all the supported encodings
    return strlen(mb_convert_encoding('a', $encoding, 'UTF-8'));
}

foreach (mb_list_encodings() as $encoding) {
    echo "$encoding: ", flawed_detection($encoding), "\n";
}
```

Partial output:

```
...
UTF-16LE: 2
UTF-8: 1
UTF-7: 1
UTF7-IMAP: 1
ASCII: 1
EUC-JP: 1
...
```

But I'm not sure of the "correct" character to use. If ever there is one.

**edit: I've tested the brute-force approach with every chars from 0 to U+10FFFF in every encodings, and the results are exactly the same that with my finally_not_so_flawed_detection function (with the 'a' char or with space) :p**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measure string size in Bytes in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568949/measure-string-size-in-bytes-in-php)

Comment: Why? What's the goal here? Do you have a valid business or technical reason to not use UTF-8 across the board?

Comment: What why? This is a general purpose question :p And I use UTF-8 in my project, but I need to decode some strings in binary files.

Comment: related brute-force approach in python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870107/mapping-of-character-encodings-to-maximum-bytes-per-character

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way you can tell for sure, but a reasonable approximation will be to check the width of the space character (`" "`, U+20, etc). As far as I know, every sane text encoding supports that character, and every variable-length encoding uses a minimum-length sequence for it.

Comment: 'a' and ' ' give the exact same results :)